# Resize image using ImageMagick and Paperclip based on center point

Tags: imagemagick, paperclip

Let's say I want an image to be resized to 100px x 100px.

I upload Picture A of 200px x 150px. I want it to resize up to ...px x 100px based on the center point. So I don't actually care about the loss sides (the resized 200px).

If I upload Picture B of 150px x 200px, likewise it should be resized to 100px x ...px.

The end result is always 100px x 100px, just that it is positioned in the center.

I have looked through examples in:

- http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry
- http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/

but can't find out how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: _I don't actually care about the loss additional pictures_ - would you explain what you mean? If you resize so that your image has a longest side of 100px (to fit into your target size) then you won't lose any part of the image, just detail. You are specifically wanting to resize, not crop, right?

Comment: The end result should be 100px x 100px without losing aspect ratio, but willing to lose some details in the image.

Comment: Do you mean it should **fit into** 100px x 100px? So, picture A becomes 100px x 75px? I ask this because you've said _without losing aspect ratio_, which I interpret to mean keeping the aspect ratio the same. Converting a 200px x 150px image (aspect ratio = 4/3) to 100px x 100px (aspect ratio = 1) forces a change to the aspect ratio. I wonder if instead you mean that you want to crop without squashing the image?

Comment: _So I don't actually care about the loss sides_ - makes me think you want a crop, not a resize. I'm confused! `:-)`

Comment: Probably resize to max 100px on either width or height, then crop the center?

Comment: Ah right, crop **and** resize! OK. Do this in two parts - first of all get IM to scale the image down to 100px on the longest side. Have a look at `man convert` for this. _Then_ do the crop on the opposite axis. I should think it would be easier to do it this way than to do it in one go (though that is probably possible as well).

Comment: Addendum - "aspect ratio" means the width of an image divided by its height. So you may wish to remove that phrase from your question - your output image will have an aspect ratio of 1, which is different to the aspect ratio of your inputs.

Comment: Great. Thanks for leading. I think I know what I should research on. Do you mind to put your comment as answer, so that I can mark it as answer? Thanks!

Comment: No worries, done. (Btw, you're welcome to tick @rodneyrehm's answer, and just +1 mine - his answer does look like what we've discussed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description I'm guessing you're talking about

1. Scaling the image to fully fill 100x100 pixel, even if that means you get 100x123 or 123x100 pixel
2. cut off any portion of the image that is outside the 100x100 pixel bounds, preferably cut out 50px to each side from the dead center of the image.

What you're talking about is thumbnail cropping. If you're using [Imagick](http://php.net/imagick), have a look at the handy little method [Imagick::cropThumbnailImage()](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropthumbnailimage.php).

If you cannot use ImageMagick via the PECL, here's the CLI for cropThumbnail:

```
convert input.png -resize '100x100^' -gravity center -extent '100x100' output.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this problem in two parts - first of all get ImageMagick to scale the image down to 100px on the <s>longest</s> shortest side. Have a look at `man convert` for how to do this. Then do the crop on the longer opposite axis, around the centre-point. I should think it would be easier to do it this way than to do it in one go, but the latter is possible with IM.

(Corrected from the version in the comments)

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I can't describe in words how thankful am I for your patience and help.